# How to convert a number to a SAS time value?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have variable in sas which has reads time as 515(numeric format), however I would like to convert it to appear 5:15 or 05:15.

```
data  output;
set old;
/* if variable name is var, what should I write here to convert 515 
   to 5:15 or to 05:15*/
run;
```

Comment: Do you want R or SAS. One tag has to be removed!

Comment: I have got the answer in R, Please help me with answer in SAS. Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to do if the number has a value greater than 59 in the tens and ones place?

Answer (score 1):

there could be easier and cleaner way then this but this also works.

```
 data  output;
var1=515;
var2= input(cats(substr(put(var1,3.),1,1),":",substr(put(var1,3.),2,3)),time5.);
format var2 time5.;
run;
```

Comment: if possible, please accept one of the answer, if you feel it has worked for you

Answer (score 0):

In R - you can convert number to time format using below regex:

```
var = 515;
var_time = sub("(\\d+)(\\d{2})", "\\1:\\2", var);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution in R however I am also looking to convert in SAS.  Thanks mate it works in R.

Comment: Beyond my realms mate.

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert to character via PUT()
2. Read it back in as time via INPUT()

   ```
   data have;
       x=515;
       sas_time = input(put(x, 8. -l), hhmmss.);
       format sas_time time5.;
   run;

   proc print;
   run;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can uses arithmetic to convert the number from your existing value into the number of seconds since midnight. Then attach the TIME. format to it so that it prints in human readable format.

```
time=hms(int(time/100),mod(time,100),0);
format time time5.;
```